# Accessing a table created with ModelBuilder by using DbSet of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code first scenario:

```
public class crmContext : DbContext
{

    public crmContext() : base("crmContext")
    {

    } // end crmContext()

    public DbSet<Pool> Pools { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Center> Centers { get; set; }

    // Po DbSet PoolAssignments?

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Pool>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Centers)
            .WithMany(p => p.Pools)
            .Map(
            m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("PoolAssignments");
                m.MapLeftKey("poolid");
                m.MapRightKey("centerid");
            });        

    } // end OnModelCreating()

} // class crmContext
```

The PoolAssignments table is created by modelBuilder and I would like to access it the same way I access Pools and Centers.  For example:

```
crmContext db = new crmContext();
Pool pool db.Pools.Find(id);
PoolAssignment pa = db.PoolAssignments.Find(id);
```

The problem with this approach is that I have not defined PoolAssignment as a class and there is no DbSet PoolAssignments in crmContext. I think I am not understanding this part of Entity Framework very well.

If I define a PoolAssignment class (together with its navigation properties) and a PoolAssignments DbSet, then the modelBuilder code becomes unnecessary. Code first will generate the table for me.

I am simply trying to understand the logic behind using modelBuilder in such a scenario. How can I access the table PoolAssignments and how can I access data with the Entity Framework if I do not define classes? I have searched for an answer but I cannot find any. I have read many articles but none seems to cover this scenario.

Comment: you are talking about `many-to-many` relationship here. there are plenty of tutorials available. for example [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx). with `modelBuilder` you can customize this relationship (name your table or columns). if you will remove it EF will create it automatically as `PoolsCenters` table (or something like this).

Comment: also, why do you even need to access `PoolAssignment `? you can add/remove  using `pool.Centers.{Add | Remove}(...)` or `center.Pools.{Add | Remove}(...)`.

Comment: Thank you ieaglle. You opened my eyes :). I got stuck on the idea that I must use a separate class.